# How to start tmux with no configuration?

Tags: tmux

How can I start `tmux` without allowing it to read any configuration files?

(I have a server with only one account, so I have to share many configuration files of many programs. This means, I cannot delete `.tmux.conf` etc.)

Comment: I assume that one shared account is the root account. If so, why don't you set up a new administrative account just for yourself?

Comment: @DavidFoerster Unfortunately, It is not the root.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `-f` option tells `tmux` to use the specified configuration file instead of the default (`/etc/tmux.conf` and `~/.tmux.conf`). You can point it at `/dev/null` to skip configuration entirely:

```
tmux -f /dev/null
```

or use your own configuration:

```
tmux -f ~/.tmux.plhn.conf
```

This will only work when *starting* `tmux`; if a `tmux` server is already running, its configuration can’t be changed in this way.

Comment: Note: You can use a different tmux socket to avoid having to kill tmux in order to test with an empty config. `tmux -L test -f /dev/null`